# Why do Delegate Syntax in C# allows +=, when always the last function will be pointed too

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have tried a very simple example using delegate and i have tried to use += similar to assigning event but always the last function get triggered. What I am wondering about is the fact if delegate only points to the last function why "+=" is allowed and whats the purpose of allowing +=

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Delegate
{
    class Program
    {
        public delegate int PointerToAddFunction(int a, int b);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PointerToAddFunction myPointerToAddFunction = null;
            myPointerToAddFunction = Add;

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Add: Result is {0}", myPointerToAddFunction.Invoke(1, 3)));

            myPointerToAddFunction = Subtract;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Substract: Result is {0}", myPointerToAddFunction.Invoke(1, 3)));


            myPointerToAddFunction += Subtract;
            myPointerToAddFunction += Add;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Both: Result is {0}", myPointerToAddFunction.Invoke(1, 3)));

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        private static int Subtract(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

One more point i would like to add from @CodesInChaos's comment

"why the CLR/C# designers decided to support multi-cast delegates that don't return void"

Comment: All of them will be called, but only the last return value will be used. I recommend only using multi-cast delegates for `void` returning functions (typically event handlers). But if you're wondering why the CLR/C# designers decided to support multi-cast delegates that don't return void, I can't answer that.

Comment: I think you'll find that both functions are called (put breakpoints or `WriteLine` calls in them). But each one returns a separate value, so only the last value is used in the output.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: When you use `delegate` in C#, the result is a multicast delegate. See, for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175.aspx

Comment: Practice using the debugger, it can easily show you that your assumptions are invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I am wondering about is the fact if delegate only points to the
>   last function why "+=" is allowed and whats the purpose of allowing +=

A delegate formed by using the `+=` operator does not point to the last function added to it. When using `+=`, the delegates get chained together to form a new delegate. That new delegate stores an invocation list of all the functions assigned to it.

The C# Specification states:

> Delegates are **combined** using the binary + (§7.8.4) and += operators
>   (§7.17.2). A delegate can be removed from a combination of delegates,
>   using the binary - (§7.8.5) and -= operators (§7.17.2). Delegates can
>   be compared for equality (§7.10.8). The following example shows the
>   instantiation of a number of delegates, and their corresponding
>   invocation lists:

```
delegate void D(int x);
class C
{
    public static void M1(int i) {...}
    public static void M2(int i) {...}
}
class Test
{
    static void Main() {
        D cd1 = new D(C.M1);        // M1
        D cd2 = new D(C.M2);        // M2
        D cd3 = cd1 + cd2;      // M1 + M2
        D cd4 = cd3 + cd1;      // M1 + M2 + M1
        D cd5 = cd4 + cd3;      // M1 + M2 + M1 + M1 + M2
    }
}
```

> When cd1 and cd2 are instantiated, they each encapsulate one method.
>   When cd3 is instantiated, it has an invocation list of **two methods**, M1
>   and M2, in that order. cd4’s invocation list contains M1, M2, and M1,
>   in that order. Finally, cd5’s invocation list contains M1, M2, M1, M1,
>   and M2, in that order.

What you experience in the following line:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Calling Both: Result is {0}",
                                 myPointerToAddFunction.Invoke(1, 3)));
```

Is because the value of the last method being invoked in the list is what gets returned back from calling the delegate:

> **15.4 Delegate Invocation**
>
> If the delegate invocation includes output parameters or a return
>   value, their final value will come from the invocation of the last
>   delegate in the list.

Comment: Where can I find `7.17.2` ? I can't find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691304%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: You can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691316(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thank @YuvalItzchakov. One more point "why it is allowed to support multi-cast delegates that don't return void" Wouldn't it create a confusion ? Or do you have any practical example in your mind in support of this Multicast delegates having return value other than void.